# Word for 'make more frequent'

Tags: synonyms

For example, how would you convert

> He made cunning remarks more frequently.

to

> He **____** his cunning remarks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps some of these might work:

- accelerated
- increased the pace of
- ramped up
- sped up

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind expressing your idea with a moderately informal tone, try

> He *upped the rate* of his cunning remarks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word but you can rephrase like this:

> He *increased the frequency of* his cunning remarks.

Answer (score 0):

- He *assiduously increased* his cunning remarks.
- He *accelerated the frequency of* his cunning remarks.
- He *proliferated* his cunning remarks.

The most suitable word is *proliferated*.

If you have been following world politics, you would notice the prominence of the issue of nuclear proliferation.

As examples to its use,

- Nuclear Proliferation is the increasing and widespread existence of nuclear armament.
- In recent decades, we have noticed the proliferated use of public obscenity among movie stars.

> [pro·lif·er·ate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/proliferate)  (prə-lĭf′ə-rāt′)
>   v. pro·lif·er·at·ed, pro·lif·er·at·ing, pro·lif·er·ates
>   v.intr.
>
> 1. To grow or multiply by rapidly producing new tissue, parts, cells, or offspring.
> 2. To increase or spread at a rapid rate: fears that nuclear weapons might proliferate.
>
> v.tr.
>   To cause to grow or increase rapidly.
>
> *The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition copyright ©2000 by Houghton Mifflin Company. Updated in 2009. Published by Houghton Mifflin Company. All rights reserved.*

Comment: Normally, I would phrase it like - He proliferated his use of obscenities. *Use of* having affinity to the word *proliferate*.